# Why am I sometimes getting files filled with zeros at their end after being downloaded?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, indy

I'm developing a download manager using `Indy` and `Delphi XE` (The application uses `Multithreading` to attempt several connections to the server). Everything works fine but sometimes the final downloaded file is broken and when I check downloaded temp files I see that 2 or 3 of them is filled with zero at their end. (Each temp file is download result of each connection).
The larger the file is, the more broken temp files I get as the result.
For example in one of the temp files which was 65,536,000 bytes, only the range of 0-34,359,426 was valid and from 34,359,427 to 64,535,999 it was full of zeros. If I delete those zeros, application will automatically download the missing segments and what I get as the result, well if the problem wouldn't happen again, is the healthy downloaded file.
I want to get rid of those zeros at the end of the temp files without having a lost in download speed.

P.S. I'm using `TFileStream` and I'm sending it directly to `TIdHTTP` and downloading the files using `GET` method.
Additional Info: I handle `OnWork` event which assigns `AWorkCount` to a public `int64` variable. Each time the file is downloaded, the downloaded file size (That `Int64` variable) is logged to a text file and from what the log says is that the file has been downloaded completely (even those zero bytes).

Comment: Are you using the Indy version that ships with Delphi XE or a newer version?

Comment: I'm using Indy 10 which comes with Delphi XE. Is there a newer version??

Comment: I'm using the latest Indy sources from the project repository here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/internetdirect/
 The latest Subversion sources are working better for me than the version that ships in XE2 does.  Both are snapshot releases, it's been a LONG time since there's been a stable release.  But I suspect your problem is more general, and probably a problem on the SERVER side that you didn't write.

Comment: It says: This project has no files. What to do?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the server actually supports downloading byte ranges before you request a range to download.  If the server does not support ranges, a requested range will be ignored by the server and the entire file will be sent instead.  If you are not already doing so, you should be using `TIdHTTP.Head()` to text for range support before then calling `TIdHTTP.Get()`.  You also need to do this anyway to detect if the remote file has been altered since the last time you downloaded it.  Any decent download manager needs to be able to handle things like that.

Also keep in mind that if `TIdHTTP` knows up front how many bytes are being transferred, it will pre-allocate the size of the destination `TStream` before then downloading data into it.  This is to speed up the transfer and optimize disc I/O when using a `TFileStream`.  So you should **NOT** use `TFileStream` to access the same file as the destination for multiple simultaneous downloads, even if they are writing to different areas of the file.  Pre-allocating multiple `TFileStream` objects will likely trample over each other trying to set the file size to different positions.  If you need to download a file in multiple pieces simultaneously then either:

1) download each piece to a separate file and copy them into the final file as needed once you have all of the pieces that you need.

2) use a custom `TStream` class, or Indy's `TIdEventStream` class, to manage the file I/O yourself so you can ignore `TIdHTTP`'s pre-allocation attempts and ensure that multiple file I/O operatons do not overlap each other incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. +1 for `TIdEventStream`.
I'm using several `TFileStream` objects writing to different files. (As you said, they are joined together at the end)
Even having `TFileStream` objects with sizes more than downloaded, isn't `OnWork` event called after writing to the file? I believe it does, so I always assume that only `AWorkCount` bytes of the target is downloaded. I don't think that would solve the problem.

Comment: `OnWork` is triggered for each block of data that gets written to the file while the download is in progress. But like I said, the files are also pre-allocated if the download size is known up-front (ie HTTP chunking is not being used). So it is possible that the final file size can be larger than the number of bytes actually downloaded, especially if the download is aborted prematurely. Knowing how many bytes were downloaded via `OnWork`, you could just manually set the file size to match after a download is finished for any reason, don't just leave it at its pre-allocated size.

Comment: I have actually done this (saving downloaded bytes count to the registry via `OnWork`) but I don't get why sometimes downloads are broken. Sometimes there are few temp files that differ completely form the original file in the same range! This problem is driving me crazy!

Comment: You will just have to run the code inside the debugger and track down where the differences are occuring.  Using TIdEventStream, for instance, you have access to the raw data that TIdHTTP is attempting to write to file.